# How long does the Mobile Android Market get updated after upgrade published?

Tags: android, google-play

After I upload/publisher a upgrade of my application, it get updated on the Web Android Market immediately. But if I search it on my phone on Android Market, it is still showing the old version?

Is this just a delay or something? How long does it take for the Mobile Android Market get updated? Is there way to expedite the process? Thanks

Comment: A few hours! Given that publishing a new app only takes a few minutes, a few hours is pretty bad. :(

Comment: In my case, in this current date, took around 2 days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually a few minutes to few hours at most.

Comment: Progress, now it is in this intermediate state: "Not found, the requested item could not be found! It seem the old version is gone, but new version is not there yet! Crap!